# How to enable 'request_new_pad' interface through gst-launch-1.0 command?

Tags: c, linux, gstreamer

I've written a Gstreamer element, you can just call it '**myelement**'. Thing is that I want to use **request_new_pad** interface of GstElement to add more sink pads, after I added the function named '**gst_my_element_request_new_pad**', I don't know how to implement this function by using **gst-launch-1.0** command.

I searched some examples online about its usage, most of the users used this interface by calling Gstreamer API, I wonder if I can debug with gst-launch-1.0?

Comment: I got it, here's an example: Let's say I have a src pad called "src", and a requested pad called "video", then the pipeline would be: #gst-launch-1.0 icamerasrc device-name=tpg num-buffers=10 name=t t.src ! queue ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=640,height=480 ! filesink location=1 t.video ! queue ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=1920,height=1080 ! filesink location=2

Comment: BTW, why the f**k GstBaseSrc allows only one srcpad? It's extremely inconvenient!!!